# Modificar un campo de registro con UPDATE y dato en una variable

Tags: vba

Estoy intentando insertar o modificar un campo llamado `nro_identificación` con una variable llamada `doc` la instrucción `INSERT` no introduce los datos que están después de `value` , solo agrega un registro en blanco en ,. Entonces, trato de introducir el dato con la instrucción `UPDATE`, pero no se usarla me da error de sintaxis, por favor solicito ayuda..

```
Private Sub Comando2_Click()
doc = InputBox("introduzca nro. de documento")
intx = DCount("*", "[pacientes]", "[nro_identificacion]= '" & doc & "'")

If intx = 0 Then
  Dim sql As String
  Dim sql2 As String
  sql2 = "UPDATE  pacientes SET nro_documento=  'doc'  where nro_documento=''"
  sql = "INSERT INTO pacientes (nro_identificacion) VALUES ('" & doc & "')"

  CurrentDb.Execute (sql)
  CurrentDb.Execute (sql2)

  DoCmd.OpenForm "principal", , , "nro_identificacion= '" & doc & "'"
  Else
  DoCmd.OpenForm "principal", , , "nro_identificacion= '" & doc & "'"
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Podrías poner el error que te marca, al parecer no estas pasando correctamente la variable doc.

Comment: Se ha producido el error '3061' en tiempo de ejecucion: pocos parametros, Se esperaba 1......Gracias

Comment: El insert: "INSERT INTO pacientes (nro_identificacion)
VALUES ( '" & doc & "')"

El Update: "UPDATE pacientes SET nro_documento = " & doc& "WHERE nro_documento =' '"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una cosa es modificar con **UPDATE** en cuyo caso le tienes que decir que modifique el registro que sea que coincida con algo, y otra cosa es insertar un nuevo registro con **INSERT**,en cuyo caso te crea un nuevo registro en la tabla.

**El INSERT es correcto**. Para aislar prueba lo siguiente:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO pacientes (nro_identificacion) VALUES ('Valor_prueba')";
```

Podrás comprobar que inserta un nuevo registro y en la columna `nro_identificacion` debe poner `Valor_prueba`

Ahora bien, para el **UPDATE** debes hacer lo siguiente.
Imagina que ya has creado el registro anterior, pues debes indicar que busque el registro y modifique su valor. Por ejemplo:

```
  sql2 = "UPDATE  pacientes SET nro_identificacion =  'Nuevo_Valor_de_prueba'  where nro_identificacion ='Valor_prueba'";
```

Si utilizas el campo `nro_documento` deberías conocer su valor primero, es decir, cuando agregues con el **INSERT** lo normal es decir:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO pacientes (nro_identificacion,nro_documento) VALUES ('Valor_prueba','DOC1')";
```

y luego si quieres modificarlo será:

```
sql2 = "UPDATE  pacientes SET nro_identificacion =  'Nuevo_Valor_de_prueba'  where nro_documento ='DOC1'";
```

Comment: Me sirvio , gracias por tu ayuda